# Read csv file from S3 with Python DictReader

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3

I am looking to write Python code that reads a csv file from S3 and then goes through the files line by line and uses the values in each line.  The example below is from realpython.org and I like how you can select the value in the row using the column header name like row["department"].

I have tried to use csv.DictReader() with the csv file I get from my S3 bucket but it returns either an `invalid argument` or `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StreamingBody` when I open the file `with open(obj['Body'], mode='r') as csv_file:`

Does the code below work with csv files read from S3 buckets?

```
import csv

with open('employee_birthday.txt', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        print(f'\t{row["name"]} works in the {row["department"]} department, and was born in {row["birthday month"]}.')
        line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to open a text document, but you're using csv.DictReader - that's your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`obj['Body']` is a `StreamingBody` object, as the error message indicates. Since it is a file-like object, you should pass it to `DictReader` instead of opening it as the path to a file, but since it returns the stream in bytes and the `DictReader` expects a text stream, you can wrap it in `io.TextIOWrapper` instead:

```
import io
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(obj['Body']))
```

Comment: Thanks.  When I do that I get the following error in the for loop that follows afterwards...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    for row in csv_reader:
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 111, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: Thanks, but that is now giving me a different error.

Comment: csv_reader = csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(obj['Body']))
AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'readable'